# Как редактировать стиль breeze Qt/GPT?

Tags: qt, gpt

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу найти нужную информацию. Можно ли как-то отредактировать стиль Breeze Qt/GPT? При изменении цвета, меняется цвет не всех элементов. Можно ли как-то переписать стиль Breeze, сделав из него другой? Есть ли какие-то инструкции?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два способа перерисовать основные виджеты Qt:

1. либо вы пишите свой QSS(аналог CSS) и возможно даже есть энтузиасты, которые делали нечто для breeze. Часто его не хватает, поэтому используют второй вариант;
2. либо вы наследуетесь от абстрактного класса QStyle и перерисовываете все, что вам нужно. Он отвечает за внешний вид, размеры и всякие тонкости отображения большинства Qt виджетов(не всех). Шире, сложнее. Хотите создать свой? Возьмите исходники breeze, найдите наследника QStyle, переопределите.